# LocalProcessingException by rendering Report

Tags: exception, pdf, visual-studio-2013, render, rdlc

It's my first time on `Visual Studio (2013)` rdlc reports in C#. When the method Render() is called it throws a LocalProcessingException.

Code

```
Assembly assembly = this.GetType().Assembly;
var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + "." + "Reports.Test.rdlc");

var report = new LocalReport();
report.SetBasePermissionsForSandboxAppDomain(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted));

report.LoadReportDefinition(stream);
var bytes = report.Render("PDF");

var pdf = new MemoryStream(bytes);
```

I'm working on a WebApplication using WebApi. I Need the pdf in a stream in order to return it to the client.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I think there is a problem with `stream` variable, since when I inspect it I see `ssss.ReadTimeout threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException` and `ssss.ReadTimeout threw an exception of type System.InvalidOperationException` but I don't know what it means.

Comment: `LocalProcessingException` is the most generic error using `LocalReport`: you have to check its `InnerException.Message` to have more info about the problem.

Comment: The InnerException: `ProcessingAbortedException {"An error has occurred during report processing."}`

Comment: `InnerException.InnerException.Message`? every `Exception` could have an `InnerException`: analyze them all until you find something usefull.

Comment: Just found the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ReportViewer` instead of calling the `LocalReport` directly.

```
ReportViewer reportViewer = new ReportViewer();
reportViewer.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Reports.Test.rdlc";
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(myDataSource);

byte[] bytes = reportViewer.LocalReport.Render("PDF");
```

Comment: What exception? As you've mentioned 2 different ones in your post. And where does it get thrown exactly?

Comment: Same as mine example: LocalProcessingException on Render()

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the problem. I was missing the following line:

```
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("MyClass", new List<MyClass>() { new MyClass(){MyProp="2"}}));
```

Added this line it works!